# Явное преобразование типов из int в decimal

Tags: c#

Всем привет, при выполнении функции в строке 22, компилятор выдает ошибку о необходимости явного преобразования (CS0266). Пытаясь выполнить явное преобразование в строке 38, компилятор выдает ошибку, что идентификатора не существует в контексте (CS0103). Как правильно выполнить преобразование чтобы функция заработала с типом decimal?

P.S.Если вместо decimal, поставить тип данных int, то все будет работать, но мне именно нужно, чтобы число можно было бы округлить до сотых.

```
// C# program Percentile calculate Percentile of AppleStocks 
using System;

namespace Test1
{
    class Program
    {

        // Функция калькуляции перцентиля
        static void percentile(decimal[] arr, decimal n)
        {
            decimal i, count, percent;

            // цикл
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                count = 0;
                for (decimal j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {

                    // сравнение 
                    if (arr[i] > arr[j]) //строка 22!
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                percent = (count * 90) / (n - 1);

                Console.Write("\nPercentile of stocks Apple for June "
                + (i + 1) + " = " + percent);



            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            var e = (double)i; //строка 38!
            decimal[] AppleStocks = { 12, 60, 80, 71, 30 };
            decimal n = AppleStocks.Length;
            percentile(AppleStocks, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы зря взяли тип `decimal` для индексов. Объявите `n` и `j` как `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Индексаторы у массивов имеют тип `int`, поэтому просто используйте его.

```cs
static void Percentile(decimal[] arr)
{
    int n = arr.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        decimal count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        { 
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        decimal percent = (count * 90) / (n - 1);

        Console.Write("\nPercentile of stocks Apple for June "
            + (i + 1) + " = " + percent.ToString("F2"));
    }
}
```

```cs
decimal[] appleStocks = { 12, 60, 80, 71, 30 };
Percentile(appleStocks);
```

Comment: @Otto Rahn Если надо хранить именно с сотыми долями как индекс - есть 2 варианта: Убедиться что индекс не может выйти за пределы int если умножить его на 100 и в таком случае хранить сотые доли как целое, пример: 1.01 -> 101. Или если кол-во записей в массиве не велико, то использовать dictionary и по необходимости сортировать его, а ещё лучше SortedList. Как более продвинутый вариант - можете написать своё продвинутое хранилище с индексаторами.